# Simplest way - only call a function when ajax-request function is completed - callback, promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have two nested functions like this:

```
var userhascompany;

$(document).ready(function(){

    checkforcompany();


        if (Object.keys(localStorage).length > 0) {

            getaddjobcache();

        }

    });
```

The `checkforcompany();` function looks like this:

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'addjob_companycheck.php',
    success: function(dataresponse) {

        userhascompany = dataresponse;

    }

});
```

The function `getaddjobcache();` should only get called, when the variable `userhascompany` has a value or rather the ajax request has finished.

Comment: What about just returning a `Promise` from checkforcompany?

Comment: Yeah, I watched some youtube content about promises and red some articles, but in every example the syntax of the code looks diffrent than what I am used to, which confuses me and I don´t understand it. So, I hope that someone could maybe do an example with my code environment, so I will maybe understand handling promises.

Answer (score 2):

Modify `checkforcompany()` to return the [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) created by [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), since it implements the [*thenable*](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-7) interface. I recommend using [jQuery 3.x for consistent promise behavior](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-and-feature-jquery-deferred-is-now-promises-a-compatible), but if you must use an older version, you can usually get away with wrapping it in a call to [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#Resolving_thenables_and_throwing_Errors) in order to coerce the behavior to that of a compliant promise.

```
function checkforcompany () {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'addjob_companycheck.php'
  });
}

$(() => {
  checkforcompany().then(dataresponse => {
    const userhascompany = dataresponse;

    if (Object.keys(localStorage).length > 0) {
      getaddjobcache(userhascompany);
    }
  });
});
```

Also don't rely on global variables in order to pass values between contexts. Make `getaddjobcache()` accept `userhascompany` as a parameter instead, as shown above.

Lastly, [`$()` is recommended by jQuery instead of `$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches for this one is using `callback functions` other is using `.then block` or `async-await`

> Using Callback function

```
var userhascompany;
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkforcompany();
});

function checkforcompany(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'addjob_companycheck.php',
        success: function(dataresponse) {
            userhascompany = dataresponse;
            if (Object.keys(localStorage).length > 0) {
                getaddjobcache();

            }
        }

    });
}
```

> Using promise .then

```
var userhascompany;
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkforcompany()
    .then(function(dataresponse){
        userhascompany = dataresponse;
        if (Object.keys(localStorage).length > 0) {
            getaddjobcache();

        }
    })
});

function checkforcompany(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addjob_companycheck.php',
            success: function(dataresponse) {
               resolve(dataresponse)
            }
            error: function(err) {
               reject(err)
            }
        });
    })
}
```

> Using jQuery ajax .done

```
var userhascompany;
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkforcompany()
    .done(function(dataresponse){
        userhascompany = dataresponse;
        if (Object.keys(localStorage).length > 0) {
            getaddjobcache();

        }
    })
});

function checkforcompany(){
    return $.ajax({
            url: 'addjob_companycheck.php',
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: You've fallen prey to the [Promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1541563)!

Comment: @Ashish, one question. :) I need to call the checkforcompany(); function without making a promise aswell. Will that work without issues?